# How to create a READ replica for postgreSql database on local machine?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-14

I have a use case where I have keep sync two databases on my local windows machine.

For example `DB_primary` and `DB_secondary` both has one table `employee`.

How to create a read replica to keep both those DBs in sync?

Please note: I am not using any cloud. I have `Postgresql v14` installed on my windows machine.

Comment: Are both database in the same instance (aka "cluster"). The it's probably more efficient to not "sync" them but to use a foreign table to access the primary table from the secondary database. Or put everything into multiple schemas on the same database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - nope, both instance are on different cluster

Comment: You can still use a foreign table.